# How to add Scrolling Functionality in Scaffold

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting the problem when I add Scrolling functionality in Scaffold, here I have tried SingleChildScrollView, CustomerScrollView, and ListView but it freezes the UI but when I replaced ti Scaffold to LayoutBuilder it works but all the background my UI got black.
I just want to add scrolling functionally to Scaffold.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () {
           ...Some Code...
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      mydata[0][i.toString()],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Quando"),
                    ),
                  )),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 6,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        choiceButton('a'),
                        choiceButton('b'),
                        choiceButton('c'),
                        choiceButton('d'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )),
              Expanded(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Text(showtimer,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 35.0,
                            fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ) // Scaffold
      );// WillPopScope
  }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you give a more specific question or sample?

Comment: when I change the portrait mode to the landscape then some of the buttons got disappeared that's why I'm adding Scrolling functionality to swipe up to see all buttons.

Comment: i recommend replacing the column with a SingleChildScrollView

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
 return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Expanded inside any scrolling container unless you wrap it in a fixed bound  on its main axis.

Like in your case main axis is vertical and you are using expanded in it, since expanded needs a bound to limit its expansion, you should've remove that expanded thing or just wrap the container in a SizedBox for a specific height.

Than you can wrap the sized box in any scroll container which suits you.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In your code, change Column to ListView, and remove the expanded widget. you can use fixed height or MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (any ratio) to the containers, or just don't specify any container height so it'll take its  children's height.

here's the code will look like:

```
body: ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
    //  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * (any ratio) / fixed height
        child: Text(
                  mydata[0][i.toString()],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontFamily: "Quando"),
                ),
      ),
      Container(
        child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    choiceButton('a'),
                    choiceButton('b'),
                    choiceButton('c'),
                    choiceButton('d'),
                  ],
                ),
      ),
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Text(showtimer,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 35.0,
                        fontFamily: "Times New Roman",
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
      )
    ],
  ),
```